# Overwriting specific lines in Python

Tags: python-3.x, fwrite

I have a simple program that manipulates some stored data on some text files. However I have to store the name and the password on different files for python to read.

I was wondering if I could get these two words (The name and the password) on two separate lines on one file and get python to overwrite just one of the lines based on what I choose to overwrite (either the password or the name).

I can get python to read specific lines with:

```
linenumber=linecache.getline("example.txt",4)
```

Ideally id like something like this:

```
linenumber=linecache.writeline("example.txt","Hello",4)
```

So this would just write "Hello" in "example.txt" only on line 4.

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to be as simple as that, I can get the words to be stored on separate files but overall doing this on a larger scale, I'm going to have a lot of text files all named differently and with different words on them.

If anyone would be able to help, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks, James.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with built in `open()` function:

```
def overwrite(filename,newline,linenumber):
    try:
        with open(filename,'r') as reading:
            lines = reading.readlines()
        lines[linenumber]=newline+'\n'
        with open(filename,'w') as writing:
            for i in lines:
                writing.write(i)
        return 0
    except:
        return 1 #when reading/writing gone wrong, eg. no such a file
```

Be careful! It is writing all the lines all over again in a loop and when it comes to exception `example.txt` may already be blank. You may want to store all the lines in list all the time to write them back to file in exception. Or keep backup of your old files.